# After installing Snow Leopard 10.6 - Software Update gets me this

Tags: macos, updates

Some of the selected updates couldn't be saved

The update could not be expanded and verified.  It may have been corrupted or tampered with during downloading.   The update will be downloaded and checked again the next time that software update runs.

An error occurred during download.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try restarting and running Software Update again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I moved the two following folders out of the way and let them rebuild.

1. ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate
2. /Library/Updates

Comment: comment by an anonymous user - "Just what exactly do you mean by "moved... out of the way"?"

Comment: 'mv ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.old' and 'mv ~/Library/Updates ~/Library/UpdatesOld' through Terminal

Comment: I think you mean /Library/Updates not ~/Library/Updates

Comment: Yes, you are correct.